# Should we have a tag for finding info about obscure games that don't warrant a full [game-name] tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

There are a a few obscure games that I know the title of, but I can't seem to find any information on them. Googling them leads to games with similar title, but after several pages I get nothing.

Is there a tag for this? Something along the lines of [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) but asking for information, not just the title.

Comment: Since you know the title of the name, why not just tag the game's title (or get someone else to make a tag for you if it doesn't exist yet)?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't think that would work out too well. The tag would only be used once and would be a big hassle to ask questions if a new tag had to be created each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty easy to create tags, and more importantly, a game's name is really the best tag to use. If you have a question about an obscure game, then like any other question for any other specific game, the specific game tag is the best way to associate that information with that game. If you're asking good questions and posting good answers, the 300 reputation needed to create tags should be available before you start to tire of asking for tag creation assistance.

A tag that exists just to "ask information" is exceptionally vague. That's what this entire *site* is about - getting answers to questions, getting information. A tag that is "I want information on a game" is pretty much as helpful as a tag that just says "I want to beat this game". It's simply way too broad on its own right to be a useful tag. Obscurity of the game itself isn't much of a helpful factor - the lack of recognition to the game's title will give you the same amount of data. This just leaves us with "information", which is, well, very undefined.

I would recommend presenting an example of the kind of question you actually want answered - tell us what game, and what kind of information you're looking for. A solid example will provide a much better example of what tags would be appropriate, by helping us know what kind of information is being sought. [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) has only one thing it seeks, after all.

Comment: And please add a wiki entry for whatever game tag you end up creating, they are of considerable help!